# How to anchor NSViewController as a popover?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, interface-builder

I have created a sample application with the following screen setup

[image]

Clicking on the load popover button simply calls the following code:

```
@IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender:self)
}
```

As you can see in the segue properties, all that segue does is loads the viewcontroller with the anchor view being the button `testAnchor3`

The problem is: I dont know why the view is not anchoring. When ever i click on the LoadPopover button, the other view controller does load as a popover, but it anchors in the middle of the screen and not under the button like its supposed to. How do i get the popover to anchor correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a outlet for your button and put it in `presentViewController:` `toView` as a view.

```
- (void)presentViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController asPopoverRelativeToRect:(NSRect)positioningRect ofView:(NSView *)positioningView preferredEdge:(NSRectEdge)preferredEdge behavior:(NSPopoverBehavior)behavior
{
  //Change the ofView to be your button outlet
  [super presentViewController:viewController asPopoverRelativeToRect:positioningRect ofView:popOverButton preferredEdge:preferredEdge behavior:behavior];
}
```

Comment: thanks a mill man. Works. I'm still looking into why the view was nill tho.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need help with anything else.